# Retrieve rtf text with images stored in SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, rtf

I want to retrieve rtf text with images stored in SQL Server database with Windows form in asp.net web form with exactly format and images.

This is the code to store in Windows form:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE questions SET ques_rich = @ques_rich WHERE quest_no = 1 ", con)

con.Open()
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ques_rich", RichTextBox1.Rtf)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

This is the code used to retrieve in asp.net:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=AHMEDHASHEM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim tbl As New DataTable
    Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "select * from questions where quest_no = 1"

    cmd1 = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con)
    Dim ds1 As New DataSet()

    Dim Adpt1 As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
    Adpt1.Fill(ds1, "questions")
    'rc = ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count

    con.Open()

    tbxTinymce.Text = ds1.Tables("questions").Rows(0)("ques_rich")
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

**Note**: I use tinymce and freetextbox controls

Also use Word document with this code:

```
Dim wordApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass()

Dim nullobj As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

Dim doc As Word.Document = wordApp.Documents.Open("c:\goinstall.doc")
Dim doc1 As Word.Document = wordApp.ActiveDocument

Dim m_Content As String = doc1.Content.Text

FreeTextBox1.Text = m_Content

doc.Close(nullobj, nullobj, nullobj)
```

That code retrieves text only without images and formatting

Comment: What datatype is `ques_rich`?  I'm thinking that there may be some implicit conversion going on.

Comment: Ques_rich datatype is Nvarchar(max)

Comment: Ok, covert the rtf file into a bye array and store in in a blob (or clob).  Your images are being implicitly converted to that columns datatype.  If you need it, I have some code to do that.

Comment: @prescott chartier can u explain with code plez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code accepts an image from a file upload stream, converts it to a byte array and stores it in the session object for later retrieval and storage into a blob in a Oracle database.

```
' Easy enough to load a file from a stream, here I get a image from a file upload
Dim TheStream As Stream = file1.PostedFile.InputStream
' Need a variable to store the image in
Dim origimage As System.Drawing.Image
' Same the uploaded image to the variable
origimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(TheStream)
' Now we need to convert it to a bye array
Dim ms2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream
' First I scale it, I don't need a huge image, you won't need to do this
origimage = ScaleImage(origimage, 320, 200) ' new scaling method
' I save it to the memory stream in preparation to converting to a byte array
origimage.Save(ms2, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
' Here I convert the file
Dim MyPhoto() As Byte = ms2.GetBuffer ' The scaled image is now stored in memory as a byte array
Session("ThePhoto") = MyPhoto ' put it into the session to retreive later
' Release the memory
ms2.Dispose()
origimage.Dispose()
```

Obviously some of this won't be relevant to your problem.  You need to load your RTF file using a filestream of some sort and then convert the file to a byte array.  Hopefully this will help to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanx for your help .. i well try that